# How to disable the users abilities for the Devexpress GridView

Tags: visual-studio-2008, gridview, devexpress

I am using the DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView within my Visual Studio 2008 application and thought I limited the abilities of the user but I was mistaken. I am programming in VB.NET but I can easily translate from C#.

I went into the properties of the gridview and set `ShowGroupPanel`, `AllowAddRows`, `AddNewColumns`, `AllowDeleteRows`, `RemoveOldColumns`, and `Editable` to false. Doing this I thought I disabled the ability of the user to delete, add and update rows along with disabling the grouping panel.

However I ran the program and when I select a row and press delete the program complains that I don't have a deleteStoredProcedure set. I looked this up and the [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q130164.aspx) it tells me to disable the command column

```
((GridViewCommandColumn)ASPxGridView1.Columns["CommandColumn"]).EditButton.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Parameters);
```

Yet when I loop through my columns I don't have a command column. [This](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/79132/270766.aspx) site tells me to catch the delete button press using `GridView1_CommandButtonInitialize` but I can't access `CommandButtonInitialize`.

In addition I discovered if I right click on the grid while the program is running I am able to make the `group by panel` show up which I specifically thought I disabled. Also by right-clicking I can open the `column chooser` which allows the user to access the columns that I don't want them to see and set to `visible=false`.

How do I completely disable the ability of the user to delete rows, open/use the column chooser and show the group by panel in the DevExpress Gridview?

EDIT:

I'm using a `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView` within a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.PanelControl` on a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm`.

I wasn't able to find any examples that were specifically for `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView` though the first link (ASP.NET) is from the DevExpress site so I was hoping they would have some correlation.

Comment: Hi,

Your question confused me :).  You are talking about ASPxGridView and XtraGrid in your question.  The first - is ASP.NET control, the second - WindowsForms Grid.  Could you please tell us which application you are creating, and which control you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK :)

You should set the columns' OptionsColumn.AllowGroup and OptionsColumn.AllowShowHide property to false.  In this case, the end-user won't be able to group by a column or move this column to the CustomizationWindow.  If you wish to remove the corresponding items from the menu, please  refer to the

[How to disable particular menu items in the default grid menus](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A47.aspx)

article.

Finally, the grid does not delete rows from the underlying DataSource if the Delete key is pressed.  There is no this functionality embedded in the Grid.  So, I think that there should be some code in your application when rows are deleted programmatically ...